# HTML form disapearing after Error/Email is sent (PHP)

Tags: php, html, forms, email

weird problem here, my html form disapears from the page when I click the send button regardless of success or not.

I display an alert box to indicate if the email was sent or not.

here is the code

```
<?php
$action = $_REQUEST['action'];
if ($action == "") /* display the contact form */ {
    ?> 
    <form  action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit"> 

        <input class="champTextFormulaire" placeholder="Votre Nom" name="name" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br> 

        <input class="champTextFormulaire" placeholder="Votre email" name="email" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br> 

        <textarea id="champMessage" placeholder="Votre Message..." name="message" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea><br> 
        <input class="btnEnvoiFormulaire" type="submit" value="Envoi"/> 
    </form> 
    <?php
} else /* send the submitted data */ {
    $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
    $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
    $message = $_REQUEST['message'];
    if (($name == "") || ($email == "") || ($message == "")) {
        print '<script type="text/javascript">';
        print 'alert("Veuillez remplir tout les champs")';
        print '</script>';
    } else {
        $from = "From: $name<$email>\r\nReturn-path: $email";
        $subject = "Message sent using your contact form";
        mail(desiletsmathieu@gmail.com", $subject, $message, $from); 
        print '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
        print 'alert("Mail envoyé")'; 
        print '</script>'; 
        } 
    }   
    }
?>
```

Comment: For one thing, get rid of `enctype="multipart/form-data"` that's for file attachments/uploading.

Comment: Guys, I have done the code edited, so added double quotes!!!

Comment: @AjithS **It's not up to you to "fix" OP's posted code**, because that's where one of  the problem was. Do a "rollback". Have you not read the editing rules?

Comment: I have updated old code

Comment: I posted a "Working" answer Mathieu. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way.

First off, you forgot a double quote just after `mail(` that read like this:

```
mail(desiletsmathieu@gmail.com", $subject, $message, $from);
```

and needed to be changed to:

```
mail("desiletsmathieu@gmail.com", $subject, $message, $from);
```

Plus `enctype="multipart/form-data"` is for file attachments/uploading so you don't need that.

I also removed this line, which was no longer required:

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit">
```

### This works and tested:

**Note:** I added a name to your submit button in order to give it an extra condition. Plus, you basically had your conditions already set, it just needed to be reworked/rethinked and using less code to achieve the same result.

```
<form action="" method="POST"> 
<input class="champTextFormulaire" placeholder="Votre Nom" name="name" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br> 

<input class="champTextFormulaire" placeholder="Votre email" name="email" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br> 

<textarea id="champMessage" placeholder="Votre Message..." name="message" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea><br> 
<input class="btnEnvoiFormulaire" type="submit" name="submit" value="Envoi"/> 
</form> 
<?php 

$name=$_REQUEST['name']; 
$email=$_REQUEST['email']; 
$message=$_REQUEST['message']; 

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if (($name=="")||($email=="")||($message=="")) 
    { 
    print '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
    print 'alert("Veuillez remplir tout les champs")'; 
    print '</script>'; 
exit;
   } 

else
{         
    $from="From: $name<$email>\r\nReturn-path: $email"; 
    $subject="Message sent using your contact form"; 
    mail("desiletsmathieu@gmail.com", $subject, $message, $from); 
    print '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
    print 'alert("Mail envoyé")'; 
    print '</script>'; 
exit;
    } 
}   
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are using `$_REQUEST['action']`

After your are submitting the form, your hidden field `action` becomes `$_REQUEST['action'];`

And after you submit the form, you get `$action = $_REQUEST['action'];` to be `submit`.

Where as you should have a blank value for `$_REQUEST['action']` to display the form.

Solution:

1) Either, modify `if ($action == "submit")`

2) Or, assign blank value to the `action` (hidden) field